# How to get the amplitude with specific frequency in FFT?

Tags: java, android

I am working on an audio analysis project and I get a problem in getting the amplitude with specific frequency in FFT?

I have searched in the Internet. Most of FFT working on audio return a single frequency only. Can we let the frequency be the input and get the relative amplitude?

Thank you